# getting sql error unknown column in where clause when trying to filter data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In the SQL query where city clause when I put string 'delhi' I get results but when I put a variable like below I get error unknown column delhi in where clause. how to solve the issue?

```
router.get('/filter/:city', (req, res) => {
  const location = req.params.city;
  const singleQuoteLocation = location.replace(/"/g, "'");
  connection.query(
    `select * from weather_data where city=${singleQuoteLocation}`,
    (err, results, field) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(results);
        console.log(results);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: what will be the output if you put console.log(singleQuoteLocation) // Delhi or 'Delhi'

Comment: before connection.query... store your query string in a variable and print that in console.: `select * from weather_data where city=${singleQuoteLocation}`

then you will see what's wrong with your formed query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a prepared statement with a `?` placeholder for the `city` value.  Then, bind a JS variable to the `?`.

```js
router.get('/filter/:city', (req, res) => {
  const location = req.params.city;
  connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM weather_data WHERE city = ?", [location],
    (err, results, field) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        res.status(200).send(results);
        console.log(results);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Note that when using a prepared statement there is no need to massage the `location` variable by doing things like wrapping in single quotes.  Instead, let your MySQL driver worry about how to handle this, via the prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but can you elaborate more like where I can find the syntax or share a helpful reference about this problem. and one more question how can I put 2  variables in the query?

Comment: [Check here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/nodejs-mysql-prepared-statements/426216).  You may use as many `?` placeholders as you like, but `?` can only appear where literal values would otherwise appear.  That is, you can't use `?` for things like column and table names.

Answer (score 0):

```
`select * from weather_data where city = \'${singleQuoteLocation}\' `
```

Comment: what this backslash does

Comment: it will ignore quotes